# How are "refs" handled in Preact?

Tags: preact

React has the concept of [`refs`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). Is there a similar concept in Preact that can be used without `preact-compat`?

I want to be able to reference elements in `Component` methods without a DOM look-up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of passing a string, you will pass a function. For example, you would render a component with `ref` as follows.

`<Slideshow ref={slideshow => this.slideshow = slideshow} />`

This means that you can now access it with `this.slideshow`.

Comment: This is how it works in React now, too - string refs have been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

As of Feburary 2016, the core Preact package supports callback refs, so you should be able to follow along with the docs that you linked.

One thing that is explicitly *not* supported in the core library is [string refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs). They have been deprecated in React for a while now and are likely to be removed, so Preact didn't implement them to begin with. If you have a need for string refs (you probably don't, unless you're using an old third party library), preact-compat supports them.

For more info, see [issue #50 on Preact's GitHub](https://github.com/developit/preact/issues/50#issuecomment-272354162).